# Validation on directive for file upload. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with validation on modal window.There is the form in window. There all input-text are with ng-required="true" but there is one input for file uploader. This file uploader is a directive and have a such look on the page.

http://prntscr.com/m0j4yd

ng-required="true" is not woking on it. I have a code of this directive.

What I must do that file requered works?

Code of derective(it is long)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15-cBVXP-o7mMmDj6PiD__TlRPhq2eSF5

Comment: please post the code instead of the screenshot

Comment: Could you show that directive here?

Comment: I edit the question with link to code